# Google script delete duplicate row, leave most recent

Tags: date, google-apps-script, duplicates, criteria, delete-row

I am scraping ticket data from gmail using the GmailApp in scripts.  However, when a ticket status changes, I get a new email and we get a new row appended with a more recent time stamp.

I want to search for the duplicate ticket number (A) and delete the older timestamp (J).

The issue I am having is that oldTime is actually the latest entry so nothing happens.

```
13007 | B | C | D | E | F | G | H | I | 2/25/2019  
13007 | B | C | D | E | F | G | H | I | 2/26/2019
```

A is the ticket number.  B-I change depending on the ticket information.  J is pulled from the email date.

```
 function removeDuplicates() {
var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
var data = sheet.getDataRange().getValues();
var newData = [];
for(i in data){
var row = data[i];
var duplicate = false;
for(j in newData){
  //If Column A in the old entry matches Column A in the new entry
  if(row[0] == newData[j][0]){
    //Pull New Timestamp and Old Timestamp
    var newTime = Date.parse(newData[j][9]);
    var oldTime = Date.parse(row[9]);
    if (newTime>oldTime) duplicate=true; // number is milliseconds in 24 hours      
  }
}
if(!duplicate){
  newData.push(row);
}
}
sheet.clearContents();
sheet.getRange(1, 1, newData.length, newData[0].length).setValues(newData);
}
```

Comment: Can you share some data?

Comment: Edited my op with example.

Comment: I know this successfully identifies the duplicates based on column A because I get var returns for newTime and oldTime.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Replacing Older Rows with newer Rows

Okay this is working on my data let's see if it works on yours.

```
function outWithTheOldInWithTheNew() {
  var sh=SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var eA=sh.getRange(2,1,sh.getLastRow()-1,sh.getLastColumn()).getValues();
  var tA=sh.getRange(2,1,sh.getLastRow()-1,1).getValues();
  var dA=sh.getRange(2,10,sh.getLastRow()-1,10).getValues();
  var uA=[];//ticket numbers
  var uB=[];//dates
  var uC=[];//entire rows
  for(var i=0;i<tA.length;i++) {
    var idx=uA.indexOf(tA[i][0]);
    if(idx==-1) {
      uA.push(tA[i][0]);
      uB.push(dA[i][0]);
      uC.push(eA[i]);
    }else if(new Date(dA[i][0]).valueOf() > new Date(uB[idx]).valueOf()) {
      uB.splice(idx,1,dA[i][0]);//replace newer dates
      uC.splice(idx,1,eA[i]);//replace newer rows
    }
  }
  sh.getRange(2,1,sh.getLastRow()-1,sh.getLastColumn()).clearContent();
  sh.getRange(2,1,uC.length,uC[0].length).setValues(uC);//newest rows
}
```

Spreadsheet before:

[image]

Spreadsheet after:

[image]

Comment: Definitely works!  Going to take me awhile to dissect how this works so I can try to learn :D