# Google script to delete duplicate row, keep most recent based on timestamp

Tags: datetime, google-apps-script, duplicates, criteria, delete-row

I am using Google form to collect data from students without logging into their Google account. However, whenever they resubmit the form, a new row gets added to the Google Sheet (responses) with a more recent time stamp.

I want to search for the duplicate name (B) and delete all the rows with an older timestamp (A).

| Hdr1 | Hdr2 | Hdr3 | Hdr4 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 3/7/2021 16:02:28 | Varun | C | D |
| 3/7/2021 16:40:15 | Kumar | C | D |
| 3/7/2021 18:09:32 | Varun | C | D |

'A' is the time stamp added automatically by Google Forms. B is the Name of the student. C-D change depending on the time of response and situation.

By running a script I want to keep the latest submission of each student and want to delete all the old responses (rows).

I tried adapting the solution given by Cooper to a very similar question here [Google script delete duplicate row, leave most recent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55634488/google-script-delete-duplicate-row-leave-most-recent) but failed to handle TimeStamp.

Kindly help me as I am a novice to this and this is required for a student project.

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't do this because it is wrong. All data should compose history over time. Just create a new sheet and pass data there via the `SORTN` formula

```
=SORTN(SORT('Form Responses'!A2:D,ROW('Form Responses'!A2:D),0),9^9,2,2,0)
```

[image]

Another way is a script. The next code updates the 'Sheet2' sheet not the 'Form Responses' sheet.

```js
function filterData() {
  const book = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  const data = book.getRange("'Form Responses'!A2:D").getValues();
  const filtered = data
    .sort((a, b) => {
      return a[0] > b[0] ? -1 : a[0] == b[0] ? 0 : 1;
    })
    .filter(
      (row, i, arr) =>
        row[0] !== '' && i === arr.findIndex((row_) => row_[1] === row[1])
    );

  book
    .getSheetByName('Sheet2')
    .clearContents()
    .getRange(1, 1, filtered.length, filtered[0].length)
    .setValues(filtered);
}
```

[image]

But if I can't stop you to delete rows then use the next case. It is based on [the snippet "delete/move rows by conditionals"](https://github.com/contributorpw/google-apps-script-snippets/blob/master/snippets/sheets/delete_move_rows_by_conditional/code.js). It builds keys dictionary then pass they to callback of `deleteRowsByConditional_`.

```js
function deleteRowsDirectly() {
  const book = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  const sheet = book.getSheetByName('Form Responses');
  const data = sheet
    .getRange('A:D')
    .getValues()
    .reduce(
      (p, row, i, arr) => {
        if (
          row[0] !== '' &&
          (!p.keys[row[1]] || row[0] > arr[p.keys[row[1]]][0])
        )
          p.keys[row[1]] = i;
        return p;
      },
      { keys: {} }
    );
  const excludes = Object.values(data.keys);
  deleteRowsByConditional_(sheet, function (_, i) {
    return excludes.indexOf(i) === -1;
  });
}

function deleteRowsByConditional_(sheet, condition, action) {
  sheet
    .getDataRange()
    .getValues()
    .forEach(
      function (_, i, arr) {
        var j = arr.length - i - 1;
        if (this.condition.apply(null, [arr, j])) {
          this.isContinue++;
          if (j > 0) return;
        }
        if (this.isContinue > 0) {
          var prevPos = j + 1;
          if (action) action(arr, prevPos, this.isContinue);
          this.sheet.deleteRows(prevPos + 1, this.isContinue);
          this.isContinue = 0;
          return;
        }
        return;
      },
      { sheet: sheet, condition: condition, isContinue: 0 }
    );
}
```

- [The live Form](https://docs.google.com/forms/d/e/1FAIpQLScgHmhGNckyr7TMZfp4Yz1sHDH1g91cCBFcNzJq5en2bj_TlQ/viewform)
- [The Sheet with code and formulas](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/15Ft2DVUZ3yEdXoVpv7dv9TrK8J0z79AmMgtxh_etySw/edit?usp=sharing)